# What is the most efficient way of finding all the factors of a number in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, performance, factorization

Can someone explain to me an efficient way of finding all the factors of a number in Python (2.7)?

I can create an algorithm to do this, but I think it is poorly coded and takes too long to produce a result for a large number.

Comment: I don't know python. But this page maybe useful for you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: How about using `primefac`? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/primefac

Comment: @Zubo `primefac` doesn't work on Python 3, it seems. At least, not on 3.9.4.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

```py
from functools import reduce

def factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, 
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))
```

This will return all of the factors, very quickly, of a number `n`.

Why square root as the upper limit?

`sqrt(x) * sqrt(x) = x`. So if the two factors are the same, they're both the square root. If you make one factor bigger, you have to make the other factor smaller. This means that one of the two will always be less than or equal to `sqrt(x)`, so you only have to search up to that point to find one of the two matching factors. You can then use `x / fac1` to get `fac2`.

The `reduce(list.__add__, ...)` is taking the little lists of `[fac1, fac2]` and joining them together in one long list.

The `[i, n/i] for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1) if n % i == 0` returns a pair of factors if the remainder when you divide `n` by the smaller one is zero (it doesn't need to check the larger one too; it just gets that by dividing `n` by the smaller one.)

The `set(...)` on the outside is getting rid of duplicates, which only happens for perfect squares. For `n = 4`, this will return `2` twice, so `set` gets rid of one of them.

Comment: trial division algorithm is the most simple one :p

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, i am new to this. Could you explain what each part of your code does? I'm new to programming. I've seen they use of sqrt in other codes for the same function, but not sure why?

Comment: I copy-pasted this from a list of algorithms on my computer, all I did was encapsulate the `sqrt` -- it's probably from before people were really thinking about supporting Python 3. I think the site I got it from tried it against `__iadd__` and it was faster. I seem to remember something about `x**0.5` being faster than `sqrt(x)` at some point though -- and it is more foolproof that way.

Comment: @agf Sorry to bug you about a post you made almost exactly a year ago. This `factors` function is very fast and neat, did you come up with this? Or do you have a source for these goodies you can share? Thanks.

Comment: @Levon No problem. As I said in a previous comment, I found this somewhere and saved it in a list of snippets. I unfortunately don't have any idea where it came from, other than that I think it was a blog post.

Comment: @agf thanks for getting back to me, it's such a clever and fast algorithm, makes me want to study these things more in depth. Working the Euler Project problems is very motivating. Thanks again.

Comment: Seems to perform 15% faster if I use `if not n % i` instead of `if n % i == 0`

Comment: @dansalmo For larger numbers, the `n//i` step will dominate anyway, but that sounds like a nice micro-optimization.

Comment: I am interested why it needs to be ``n//i``. Doesn't the ``if n % i == 0`` eliminate the need for flooring the result?

Comment: @sthzg We want it to return an integer, not a float, and on Python 3 `/` will return a float even if both arguments are integers and they are exactly divisable, i.e. `4 / 2 == 2.0` not `2`.

Comment: @agf I thought something along that line and checked the 2.7 docs and the Python console, where it remained an integer. So it's a 3.x thing, very good to know.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but in Python 3.x you need to add `from functools import reduce` to make this work.

Comment: Consider using `pow()` instead of `**` - I believe `pow(n,0.5)` is O(1) whereas `n**0.5` is O(N). This is likely to make a significant difference as`n` gets larger

Comment: @unseen_rider: That doesn’t sound right. Can you provide anything to back it up?

Comment: @ryan what comment / answer edit are you referring to?

Comment: @unseen_rider: “I believe `pow(n,0.5)` is O(1) whereas `n**0.5` is O(N)”

Comment: c++ pow() function is constant time - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418180/time-complexity-of-c-math-library-pow-function. I understand that python `pow()` calls or implements the c++ pow() function

Comment: Using `**` for exponentiation is significantly slower for large `n`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019740/speed-of-calculating-powers-in-python

Comment: @unseen_rider: Python's `pow` builtin function and `**` operator wrap _exactly_ the same underlying code. See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e8eb972514cad6086b752754c1d34d703c04dd82/Python/ceval.c#L1187) for `**` and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e8eb972514cad6086b752754c1d34d703c04dd82/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1845) for the `pow` builtin function. A `pow` call requires an extra name lookup, but the complexity will be identical.

Comment: @unseen_rider: Both of them use O(1) floating-point exponentiation (“c++ pow()”) when either operand isn’t an integer, and that’s the case here.

Comment: `reduce(list.__add__, ...)` is an unperformant way to flatten a list. see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/0ed8e599cbc8a8605abbe919df84c5fa). You *could* use `reduce(list.__iadd__,...,[])` but that is inelegantly mixing side-effects with functional constructs.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga [steveha's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909532/500584) gives some nice versions that don't have list creation overhead.

Comment: This is clever in reducing the time complexity of generating the factors to O(n**0.5), but what is the complexity of using `set` to remove duplicates?

Comment: @dansalmo @agf using `if not n%i` is a consistent 20-30% speedup on my machine on `n` up to 100,000 (2013 MBP w/i7) using Python 3.6.7.  `pow**0.5` vs `pow(n,0.5)` vs `sqrt(n)` seems to make no difference at all in my limited testing.

Comment: @agf The body of the answer talks about `sqrt` but that's not visible in the code provided. it looks like the edits to the code block have caused it to drift.

Comment: Probably add `sorted()` to make it cleaner. It's hard to use this in math if the factors are willy-nilly.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you need to evaluate this a lot of times, functools.cache decorator is perfect for this type of function

Answer (score 73):

The solution presented by @agf is great, but one can achieve ~50% faster run time for an arbitrary **odd** number by checking for parity. As the factors of an odd number always are odd themselves, it is not necessary to check these when dealing with odd numbers.

I've just started solving [Project Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Euler) puzzles myself. In some problems, a divisor check is called inside two nested `for` loops, and the performance of this function is thus essential.

Combining this fact with agf's excellent solution, I've ended up with this function:

```
from functools import reduce
from math import sqrt
def factors(n):
        step = 2 if n%2 else 1
        return set(reduce(list.__add__,
                    ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n))+1, step) if n % i == 0)))
```

However, on small numbers (~ < 100), the extra overhead from this alteration may cause the function to take longer.

I ran some tests in order to check the speed. Below is the code used. To produce the different plots, I altered the `X = range(1,100,1)` accordingly.

```
import timeit
from math import sqrt
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, legend, show

def factors_1(n):
    step = 2 if n%2 else 1
    return set(reduce(list.__add__,
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n))+1, step) if n % i == 0)))

def factors_2(n):
    return set(reduce(list.__add__,
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(sqrt(n)) + 1) if n % i == 0)))

X = range(1,100000,1000)
Y = []
for i in X:
    f_1 = timeit.timeit('factors_1({})'.format(i), setup='from __main__ import factors_1', number=10000)
    f_2 = timeit.timeit('factors_2({})'.format(i), setup='from __main__ import factors_2', number=10000)
    Y.append(f_1/f_2)
plot(X,Y, label='Running time with/without parity check')
legend()
show()
```

**X = range(1,100,1)**
[image: X = range(1,100,1)]

No significant difference here, but with bigger numbers, the advantage is obvious:

**X = range(1,100000,1000) (only odd numbers)**
[image: X = range(1,100000,1000) (only odd numbers)]

**X = range(2,100000,100) (only even numbers)**
[image: X = range(2,100000,100) (only even numbers)]

**X = range(1,100000,1001) (alternating parity)**
[image: X = range(1,100000,1001) (alternating parity)]

Answer (score 38):

There is an industry-strength algorithm in SymPy called [factorint](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/ntheory.html?highlight=factorint#sympy.ntheory.factor_.factorint):

```
>>> from sympy import factorint
>>> factorint(2**70 + 3**80) 
{5: 2,
 41: 1,
 101: 1,
 181: 1,
 821: 1,
 1597: 1,
 5393: 1,
 27188665321L: 1,
 41030818561L: 1}
```

This took under a minute. It switches among a cocktail of methods. See the documentation linked above.

Given all the prime factors, all other factors can be built easily.

---

Note that even if the accepted answer was allowed to run for long enough (i.e. an eternity) to factor the above number, for some large numbers it will fail, such the following example. This is due to the sloppy `int(n**0.5)`. For example, when `n = 10000000000000079**2`, we have

```
>>> int(n**0.5)
10000000000000078L
```

Since [10000000000000079 is a prime](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/primefactorscalculator.htm), the accepted answer's algorithm will never find this factor. Note that it's not just an off-by-one; for larger numbers it will be off by more. For this reason it's better to avoid floating-point numbers in algorithms of this sort.

Comment: It doesn't find all divisors but only prime factors so it's not really an answer. You should show how all other factors can be built, not just say it's easy ! By the way, sympy.divisors may be a better match to answer this question.

Comment: And note that sympy.divisors is not much faster than the accepted solution.

Comment: @ColinPitrat: I kind of doubt that `sympy.divisors` isn’t much faster, for numbers with few divisors in particular. Got any benchmarks?

Comment: @Ry I did one when I wrote this comment a year ago. It takes 2 min to write one so feel free to double check.

Comment: @ColinPitrat: Checked. As expected, the accepted answer is about the same speed as `sympy.divisors` for 100,000 and slower for anything higher (when speed actually matters). (And, of course, `sympy.divisors` works on numbers like `10000000000000079**2`.)

Comment: You only have to try with numbers like `10**n` to see that SymPy's `divisors` function is far faster than any of the other answers if the input is at all large. Few of the other answers are even correct for integers above `~10**15` given the use of `sqrt` or `n ** 0.5` etc.

Comment: Small note: since Python3.8, the `math` module includes [`isqrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isqrt), which provides the exact value needed. Of course, `factorint` is better.

Answer (score 32):

agf's answer is really quite cool.  I wanted to see if I could rewrite it to avoid using `reduce()`.  This is what I came up with:

```py
import itertools
flatten_iter = itertools.chain.from_iterable
def factors(n):
    return set(flatten_iter((i, n//i) 
                for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1) if n % i == 0))
```

I also tried a version that uses tricky generator functions:

```py
def factors(n):
    return set(x for tup in ([i, n//i] 
                for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1) if n % i == 0) for x in tup)
```

I timed it by computing:

```
start = 10000000
end = start + 40000
for n in range(start, end):
    factors(n)
```

I ran it once to let Python compile it, then ran it under the time(1) command three times and kept the best time.

- reduce version: 11.58 seconds
- itertools version: 11.49 seconds
- tricky version: 11.12 seconds

Note that the itertools version is building a tuple and passing it to flatten_iter().  If I change the code to build a list instead, it slows down slightly:

- iterools (list) version: 11.62 seconds

I believe that the tricky generator functions version is the fastest possible in Python.  But it's not really much faster than the reduce version, roughly 4% faster based on my measurements.

Comment: you could simplify the "tricky version" (remove unnecessary `for tup in`): `factors = lambda n: {f for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1) if n % i == 0 for f in [i, n//i]}`

Answer (score 21):

Here's an alternative to @agf's solution which implements the same algorithm in a more pythonic style:

```
def factors(n):
    return set(
        factor for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0
        for factor in (i, n//i)
    )
```

This solution works in both Python 2 and Python 3 with no imports and is much more readable. I haven't tested the performance of this approach, but asymptotically it should be the same, and if performance is a serious concern, neither solution is optimal.

Answer (score 14):

For n up to 10**16 (maybe even a bit more), here is a fast pure Python 3.6 solution,

```
from itertools import compress

def primes(n):
    """ Returns  a list of primes < n for n > 2 """
    sieve = bytearray([True]) * (n//2)
    for i in range(3,int(n**0.5)+1,2):
        if sieve[i//2]:
            sieve[i*i//2::i] = bytearray((n-i*i-1)//(2*i)+1)
    return [2,*compress(range(3,n,2), sieve[1:])]

def factorization(n):
    """ Returns a list of the prime factorization of n """
    pf = []
    for p in primeslist:
      if p*p > n : break
      count = 0
      while not n % p:
        n //= p
        count += 1
      if count > 0: pf.append((p, count))
    if n > 1: pf.append((n, 1))
    return pf

def divisors(n):
    """ Returns an unsorted list of the divisors of n """
    divs = [1]
    for p, e in factorization(n):
        divs += [x*p**k for k in range(1,e+1) for x in divs]
    return divs

n = 600851475143
primeslist = primes(int(n**0.5)+1) 
print(divisors(n))
```

Comment: This is by far the fastest method here for very large numbers. But for some reason it throws `SystemError: deallocated bytearray object has exported buffers` when you put it in a file and run it as you would normally do from the console: `py -3 test.py` when you set the `n` to a very large number, for example. `n = 326832565659962601981259122112549`. The weird thing - it works when you run it directly from the python console `py -3`, but throws the error when you run  `py -3 test.py`

Answer (score 13):

An alternative approach to agf's answer:

```
def factors(n):    
    result = set()
    for i in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        div, mod = divmod(n, i)
        if mod == 0:
            result |= {i, div}
    return result
```

Comment: Can you explain the div, mod part?

Comment: divmod(x, y) returns ((x-x%y)/y, x%y), i.e., the quotient and remainder of the division.

Comment: This doesn't handle duplicate factors well - try 81 for example.

Comment: Your answer is clearer, so I was able to grok it just enough to misunderstand. I was thinking of prime factorization where you'd want to call out multiple 3's. This should be fine, as that is what the OP asked for.

Comment: I piled everything into one line because agf's answer did so.  I was interested in seeing whether `reduce()` was significantly faster, so I pretty much did everything other than the `reduce()` part the same way agf did.  For readability, it would be nice to see a function call like `is_even(n)` rather than an expression like `n % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way of finding factors of a number:

```
def factors(x):
    return [i for i in range(1,x+1) if x%i==0]
```

Comment: Compared to other answers, this may not be as efficient, since the OP requests for efficiency specifically

Comment: @SreenikethanI Totally agree with you. That is why I wrote "simplest", not "efficient". This answer might be helpful for those who just need quick solution, and they are doing some basic stuff

Answer (score 8):

I've tried most of these wonderful answers with timeit to compare their efficiency versus my simple function and yet I constantly see mine outperform those listed here. I figured I'd share it and see what you all think.

```
def factors(n):
    results = set()
    for i in xrange(1, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            results.add(i)
            results.add(int(n/i))
    return results
```

As it's written you'll have to import math to test, but replacing math.sqrt(n) with n**.5 should work just as well. I don't bother wasting time checking for duplicates because duplicates can't exist in a set regardless.

Comment: Great stuff! If you put int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1 outside of the for loop you should get bit more performance out of it since won't have to re-calc it each iteration of the for loop

Comment: @TristanForward: That’s not how for loops work in Python. `xrange(1, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1)` is evaluated once.

Comment: `xrange` is Python 2. This is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

Further improvement to afg & eryksun's solution.
The following piece of code returns a sorted list of all the factors without changing run time asymptotic complexity:

```
    def factors(n):    
        l1, l2 = [], []
        for i in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
            q,r = n//i, n%i     # Alter: divmod() fn can be used.
            if r == 0:
                l1.append(i) 
                l2.append(q)    # q's obtained are decreasing.
        if l1[-1] == l2[-1]:    # To avoid duplication of the possible factor sqrt(n)
            l1.pop()
        l2.reverse()
        return l1 + l2
```

Idea: Instead of using the list.sort() function to get a sorted list which gives nlog(n) complexity; It is much faster to use list.reverse() on l2 which takes O(n) complexity. (That's how python is made.) 
After l2.reverse(), l2 may be appended to l1 to get the sorted list of factors.

Notice, l1 contains **i**-s which are increasing. l2 contains **q**-s which are decreasing. Thats the reason behind using the above idea.

Comment: Pretty sure `list.reverse` is O(n) not O(1), not that it changes the overall complexity.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I made a mistake. Should be O(n). (I have updated the answer now to the correct one)

Comment: It is around 2 times slower than @ steveha's or @agf's solutions.

Comment: You can pick up a small (2-3%) speed improvement by returning `l1 + l2.reversed()` rather than reversing the list in place.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another alternate without reduce that performs well with large numbers. It uses `sum` to flatten the list.

```
def factors(n):
    return set(sum([[i, n//i] for i in xrange(1, int(n**0.5)+1) if not n%i], []))
```

Comment: This does not, it is unecessarily quadratic time. Don't use `sum` or `reduce(list.__add__)` to flatten a list.

Answer (score 5):

I have recently developed a new approach for integer factorization, called Smooth Subsum Search (SSS). Here is my implementation in Python: https://github.com/sbaresearch/smoothsubsumsearch

It can factor 30-digit numbers in around 0.2 seconds, 40-digit numbers in around 2 seconds, 50-digit numbers in around 30 seconds, 60-digit numbers in around 200 seconds and 70-digit numbers in around 3000 seconds. Compared to the Self-Initializing Quadratic Sieve implementation in sympy, which is the most efficient Quadratic Sieve implementation in Python that I could find, it runs around 5 to 7 times faster. SSS is described in great detail in: https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.10529

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to grab the number larger than `sqrt(number_to_factor)` for unusual numbers like 99 which has 3*3*11 and `floor sqrt(99)+1 == 10`.

```
import math

def factor(x):
  if x == 0 or x == 1:
    return None
  res = []
  for i in range(2,int(math.floor(math.sqrt(x)+1))):
    while x % i == 0:
      x /= i
      res.append(i)
  if x != 1: # Unusual numbers
    res.append(x)
  return res
```

Comment: It doesn't produces all factors of a number. It compute prime factors of a number e.g., for [`x=8` expected: `[1, 2, 4, 8]`, got: `[2, 2, 2]`](http://ideone.com/gL7YjY)

Comment: 11 is found when 9 is comupted in the code given by @agf. `i = 9 -> 99%9 == 0 -> 9 and 99/9=11 is added.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example if you want to use the primes number to go a lot faster. These lists are easy to find on the internet. I added comments in the code.

```
# http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt
# First 10000 primes

_PRIMES = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 
        31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 
        73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 
        127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 
        179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 
        233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 
        283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 
        353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 
        419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 
        467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 
        547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 
        607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 
        661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 
        739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 
        811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 
        877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 
        947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009, 1013, 
# Mising a lot of primes for the purpose of the example
)


from bisect import bisect_left as _bisect_left
from math import sqrt as _sqrt


def get_factors(n):
    assert isinstance(n, int), "n must be an integer."
    assert n > 0, "n must be greather than zero."
    limit = pow(_PRIMES[-1], 2)
    assert n <= limit, "n is greather then the limit of {0}".format(limit)
    result = set((1, n))
    root = int(_sqrt(n))
    primes = [t for t in get_primes_smaller_than(root + 1) if not n % t]
    result.update(primes)  # Add all the primes factors less or equal to root square
    for t in primes:
        result.update(get_factors(n/t))  # Add all the factors associted for the primes by using the same process
    return sorted(result)


def get_primes_smaller_than(n):
    return _PRIMES[:_bisect_left(_PRIMES, n)]
```

Comment: I created a project on Github: https://github.com/Pierre-Thibault/Factor.

Answer (score 2):

a potentially more efficient algorithm than the ones presented here already (especially if there are small prime factons in `n`). the trick here is to **adjust the limit** up to which trial division is needed every time prime factors are found:

```
def factors(n):
    '''
    return prime factors and multiplicity of n
    n = p0^e0 * p1^e1 * ... * pk^ek encoded as
    res = [(p0, e0), (p1, e1), ..., (pk, ek)]
    '''

    res = []

    # get rid of all the factors of 2 using bit shifts
    mult = 0
    while not n & 1:
        mult += 1
        n >>= 1
    if mult != 0:
        res.append((2, mult))

    limit = round(sqrt(n))
    test_prime = 3
    while test_prime <= limit:
        mult = 0
        while n % test_prime == 0:
            mult += 1
            n //= test_prime
        if mult != 0:
            res.append((test_prime, mult))
            if n == 1:              # only useful if ek >= 3 (ek: multiplicity
                break               # of the last prime) 
            limit = round(sqrt(n))  # adjust the limit
        test_prime += 2             # will often not be prime...
    if n != 1:
        res.append((n, 1))
    return res
```

this is of course still trial division and nothing more fancy. and therefore still very limited in its efficiency (especially for big numbers without small divisors).

this is python3; the division `//` should be the only thing you need to adapt for python 2 (add `from __future__ import division`).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any libraries, then I think this is the easiest way to do it:

```
def factors(n):
    l = [] # empty list
    # appending the factors in the list
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i==0:
            l.append(i)
    return l
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution using cypari library in python.
Here's [a link](https://pypi.org/project/cypari/)!

```
import cypari
def get_divisors(n):
   divisors = cypari.pari('divisors({})'.format(n))
   return divisors
print(get_divisors(24))
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24]
```

Answer (score 2):

While the question says Python (2.7), people may be interested in this simple solution using Numpy.

```
import numpy as np

t=np.arange(2,n,1)
t[n%t==0]
```

This will not return `1` nor the number itself `n`. So it will return an empty array if `n` is prime.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little surprised I couldn't find a simple implementation for integer prime factorization in the form `(p1 ** e1) * (p2  ** e2) ...`, so I decided to write my own.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

def factorize(n):
    factors = defaultdict(int)
    for i in count(2):
        while n % i == 0:
            factors[i] += 1
            n /= i

        if n == 1:
            return factors
```

This function returns a dictionary where the keys are the prime factors, and the values are the exponents. So for example:

```
>>> factorize(608)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {2: 5, 19: 1})
>>> factorize(1152)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {2: 7, 3: 2})
>>> factorize(1088)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {2: 6, 17: 1})
```

This is obviously not the most efficient implementation — for one it iterates over the whole set of natural numbers, instead of going straight for the primes — but it's good enough for relatively small values, and simple enough that it can be easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

Using `set(...)` makes the code slightly slower, and is only really necessary for when you check the square root. Here's my version:

```
def factors(num):
    if (num == 1 or num == 0):
        return []
    f = [1]
    sq = int(math.sqrt(num))
    for i in range(2, sq):
        if num % i == 0:
            f.append(i)
            f.append(num/i)
    if sq > 1 and num % sq == 0:
        f.append(sq)
        if sq*sq != num:
            f.append(num/sq)
    return f
```

The `if sq*sq != num:` condition is necessary for numbers like 12, where the square root is not an integer, but the floor of the square root is a factor.

Note that this version doesn't return the number itself, but that is an easy fix if you want it. The output also isn't sorted.

I timed it running 10000 times on all numbers 1-200 and 100 times on all numbers 1-5000. It outperforms all the other versions I tested, including dansalmo's, Jason Schorn's, oxrock's, agf's, steveha's, and eryksun's solutions, though oxrock's is by far the closest.

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty surprised when I saw this question that no one used numpy even when numpy is **way faster** than python loops. By implementing @agf's solution with numpy and it turned out at average **8x faster**.
I belive that if you implemented some of the other solutions in numpy you could get amazing times.

Here is my function:

```
import numpy as np
def b(n):
    r = np.arange(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1)
    x = r[np.mod(n, r) == 0]
    return set(np.concatenate((x, n / x), axis=None))
```

Notice that the numbers of the x-axis are not the input to the functions. The input to the functions is 2 to the the number on the x-axis minus 1.
So where ten is the input would be 2**10-1 = 1023

[image: Performance test results of using numpy instead of for loops.]

Comment: If you’re going to use a library, may as well make it the right one: SymPy, as seen in Evgeni Sergeev’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

your max factor is not more than your number, so, let's say

```
def factors(n):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, n//2+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append (i)
    factors.append(n)

    return factors
```

voilá!

Answer (score 1):

```
 import math

    '''
    I applied finding prime factorization to solve this. (Trial Division)
    It's not complicated
    '''


    def generate_factors(n):
        lower_bound_check = int(math.sqrt(n))  # determine lowest bound divisor range [16 = 4]
        factors = set()  # store factors
        for divisors in range(1, lower_bound_check + 1):  # loop [1 .. 4]
            if n % divisors == 0:
                factors.add(divisors)  # lower bound divisor is found 16 [ 1, 2, 4]
                factors.add(n // divisors)  # get upper divisor from lower [ 16 / 1 = 16, 16 / 2 = 8, 16 / 4 = 4]
        return factors  # [1, 2, 4, 8 16]


    print(generate_factors(12)) # {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12} -> pycharm output

 Pierre Vriens hopefully this makes more sense. this is an O(nlogn) solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following lambda function,

```
factor = lambda x:[(ele,x/ele) for ele in range(1,x//2+1) if x%ele==0 ]
```

factor(10)

output: [(1, 10.0), (2, 5.0), (5, 2.0)]

This function returns all the factors of the given number in list.

Answer (score 0):

Use something as simple as the following list comprehension, noting that we do not need to test 1 and the number we are trying to find:

```
def factors(n):
    return [x for x in range(2, n//2+1) if n%x == 0]
```

In reference to the use of square root, say we want to find factors of 10.  The integer portion of the `sqrt(10) = 4` therefore `range(1, int(sqrt(10))) = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and testing up to 4 clearly misses 5.

Unless I am missing something I would suggest, if you must do it this way, using `int(ceil(sqrt(x)))`.  Of course this produces a lot of unnecessary calls to functions.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that it checks many numbers that can't possibly be factors -- and it checks the higher of each factor-pair separately when you already know it is a factor after finding the smaller of the factor-pair.

Comment: @JasonSchorn: When you find 2, you immediately know that 10/2=5 is a divisor as well, no need to check 5 separately! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think for readability and speed @oxrock's solution is the best, so here is the code rewritten for python 3+:

```
def num_factors(n):
    results = set()
    for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % i == 0: results.update([i,int(n/i)])
    return results
```

Answer (score 0):

loop until you find a duplicate in x or v of the tuple where x is the denominator and v is the resultant.

```
number=30
tuple_list=[]
for i in np.arange(1,number):
    if number%i==0:
         other=int(number/i)
         if any([(x,v) for (x,v) in tuple_list if (i==x) or (i==v)])==True:
             break
         tuple_list.append((i,other))
    
 flattened = [item for sublist in tuple_list for item in sublist]              
 print(sorted(flattened))
```

output

```
 [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the number is positive integer, you may use this approach:

```
number = int(input("Enter a positive number to find factors: "))
factor = [num for num in range(1,number+1) if number % num == 0]
for fac in factor: print(f"{fac} is a factor of {number}")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'dart:math';
generateFactorsOfN(N){
  //determine lowest bound divisor range
  final lowerBoundCheck = sqrt(N).toInt();
  var factors = Set<int>(); //stores factors
  /**
   * Lets take 16:
   * 4 = sqrt(16)
   * start from 1 ...  4 inclusive
   * check mod 16 % 1 == 0?  set[1, (16 / 1)]
   * check mod 16 % 2 == 0?  set[1, (16 / 1) , 2 , (16 / 2)]
   * check mod 16 % 3 == 0?  set[1, (16 / 1) , 2 , (16 / 2)] -> unchanged
   * check mod 16 % 4 == 0?  set[1, (16 / 1) , 2 , (16 / 2), 4, (16 / 4)]
   *
   *  ******************* set is used to remove duplicate
   *  ******************* case 4 and (16 / 4) both equal to 4
   *  return factor set<int>.. this isn't ordered
   */

  for(var divisor = 1; divisor <= lowerBoundCheck; divisor++){
    if(N % divisor == 0){
      factors.add(divisor);
      factors.add(N ~/ divisor); // ~/ integer division 
    }
  }
  return factors;
}
```

Comment: Almost all the algorithm here limit to the range to the number * .5, but actually that range is much smaller. its  actually sqrt of the number. if we have the lower divisor we can get he upper one easily. since its just the number / divisor. for 16 i get 4 for the sqrt, then loop from 1 to 4. since 2 is a lower bound divisor of 16 we take 16 / 2 to get 8. if we have 1 then to get 16 is (16 / 1). I came up this while learning about prime factorization so i dont know if it is published somewhere else, but it works even for large numbers. I can provide a python solution.

Comment: supposed to be in python

Answer (score -5):

**I reckon this is the simplest way to do that:**

```
    x = 23

    i = 1
    while i <= x:
      if x % i == 0:
        print("factor: %s"% i)
      i += 1
```

Comment: Your answer, whilst giving the right result, is very inefficient. Have a look at the accepted answer. An explanation of how it solves the problem always helps an answer be more useful.