# representation of a number as multiplication of its factors

Tags: python

I want to represent a number as the product of its factors.The number of factors that are used to represent the number should be from 2 to number of prime factors of the same number(this i s the maximum possible number of factors for a number).

for example taking the number 24:

representation of the number as two factors multiplication are `2*12`, `8*3`, `6*4` and so on...,

representation of the number as three factors multiplication are `2*2*6`, `2*3*4` and so on...,

representation of the number as four factors multiplication(prime factors alone) are `2*2*2*3`.

please help me get some simple and generic algorithm for this

Comment: So given 24, what should this hypothetical function return?  [2,12]?  [8,3]?  [3,8]? -- Also, I think you'll get a lot more response on a question like this if you try something and then come back with a specific question if it doesn't work.

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python). That will give you the factors. Then you just have to manipulate them.

Answer (score 2):

This will generate all the sets of factors which multiply to give the original number. It returns all the product sets as a unique list of sorted tuples.

The `1`s are excluded, to avoid infinite recursion.

```
def prime_factors(n):    
    return set(reduce(list.__add__, ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5) + 1) if n % i == 0)))

def product_sets(n):
    return set(products(1, [], n, prime_factors(n)))



def products(current_product, current_list, aim, factors):

    if current_product == aim:
        yield tuple(sorted(current_list))

    elif 0 < current_product < aim:
        for factor in factors:
            if factor != 1:
                for product in products(current_product * factor, current_list + [factor], aim, factors):
                    yield product


print list(product_sets(24))
```

Output:

```
[(4, 6), (3, 8), (2, 12), (2, 3, 4), (24,), (2, 2, 6), (2, 2, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: @user2095966 - perhaps you could mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know one...

If you're using python, you can use dictionary's to simplify the storage...

You'll have to check for every prime less than square root of the number.

Now, suppose p^k divides your number n, your task, I suppose is to find k.
Here's the method:

> int c = 0; int temp = n; while(temp!=0) { temp /= p; c+= temp; }

The above is a C++ code but you'll get the idea...
At the end of this loop you'll have c = k

And yeah, the link given by will is a perfect python implementation of the same algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that returns all the factors of a given number, `n`. Note that it returns every single factor, not a specific pair.

```
def factors(n):
    """Finds all the factors of 'n'"""
    fList, num, y, limit = [], n, 0, int(sqrt(n)) + 1
    for factor in range(1, limit):
        if n % factor == 0:
            if factor not in fList: fList.append(factor)
            y = n / factor
            if y not in fList: fList.append(y)
    return sorted(fList)
```

For example, `factors(24)`:

```
>>> factors(24)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24]
```