# Find the highest number of divisors between range in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, I am giving two numbers,

```
a = 2
b = 9
```

`a and b` are inclusive range i.e; `(2,3,..,9)`. and my expectation for highest number of divisors are `6 and 8`.

Solution Explanation:

```
 4 = 2 * 2(one factor)
 6 = 2 * 3(two factor)
 8 = 2 * 4(two factor)
 9 = 3 * 3(one factor)
```

So, Need to Choose highest number of factors.

How to list the highest number of divisors in python from above logic ?.

**Ex:**

If I give the range `(1,2,..,10)`. Then it should gave the result of highest number of divisors are `6,8 and 10`.

and so on..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python

Comment: ... and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: Please explain the question clearly.

Comment: @codeimplementer Highest number of divisors of what?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? We don't simply write your code for you, we help you fix your own

Comment: This is obviously a homework/assignment question and the problem and solution is well understood and all over the internet and in classical programming texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This perhaps is what you're looking for:

```
import operator


def higest_divisors(a, b):
    _ret = {var: len([x for x in range(a, b+1) if not var % x]) for var in range(a, b+1)}.items()
    max = 0
    _to_ret = []
    for n, t in sorted(_ret, key=operator.itemgetter(1))[::-1]:
        if max <= t:
            _to_ret.append(n)
            max = t

    return _to_ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print higest_divisors(2, 10)
```

## EDIT

This looks a lot better:

```
from itertools import takewhile
import operator


def highest_divisors(a, b):
    _divisors = sorted({var: len([x for x in range(a, b + 1) if not var % x])
                        for var in range(a, b + 1)}.iteritems(),
                       key=operator.itemgetter(1))[::-1]
    _max = _divisors[0][1]
    return [n for n, v in takewhile(lambda y: y[1] == _max, _divisors)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for var in highest_divisors(2, 10):
        print var
```

Comment: Horrible code, I know, but its still a work in progress :P

Comment: Seriously? naming a variable as `max`? ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye not a complete disaster for a local variable :)

Comment: @thefourtheye I _did_ say its a work in progress :D

Comment: @thefourtheye Do you like the _newer_ version more?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Sorry. Looks inefficient to me :(

Comment: @thefourtheye Shouldn't be. Its done in a dictionary comprehension and list comprehension, it should be quite fast.