# Python: Only return integers

Tags: python, integer

I want to find the prime factors for 13195.

```
for num in range(1,13196):
    x = 13195/num
```

I want x to only store integers. I've tried is.integer and but keep getting syntax errors.

Comment: Try using isinstance(int)

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [modulo operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to check if a number is divided evenly, and only set x equal to it then. E.g.:

```
for num in range(1,13196):
    if 13195 % num == 0:
        x = int(13195/num)
        print(x)
```

which gives:

```
13195
2639
1885
1015
455
377
203
145
91
65
35
29
13
7
5
1
```

Comment: No need for the `int` call if you use `//`.

Comment: You could also use `divmod(13195, num)` to get both the quotient and remainder as a tuple.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod

Answer (score 3):

> I've tried is.integer and but keep getting syntax errors.

The method for checking if a float is an integer is called `is_integer()` not `is.integer()`, so alternatively, you can do this:

```
for num in range(1,13196):
    x = 13195/num 
    if x.is_integer():
        print(num)
```

Or by adding the brackets:

```
for num in range(1,13196):
    if (13195/num).is_integer():
        print(num)
```