# How to reduce time limit in python when we dealing with large length of numbers

Tags: python

As val is large.So it is not executing code.What can we do to solve this problem.

```
val = 78478277380 
i = 2
while i < val:
   if val % i == 0:
       print(i)
   i += 1
```

I want all factors of the val.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not executing code" ? What happens? Any errors?

Comment: The number doesn't have too many factors?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python) for other solutions to the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Running this on my machine, I get the first 5 factors: `2, 4, 5, 10, 20` and then it goes quiet for a while. This is not because it stopped running, but because I'm pretty sure the next factor is `3923913869` which will take a while to find. [Source](https://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you print the all the numbers, you will get a better idea of what is happening:

```
val = 78478277380
i = 2
while i < val:
   print(str(i) + "is a not factor")
   if val % i == 0:
       print(str(i) + "is a factor")
   i += 1
```

The problem is that there aren't too many factors for this number.