# calculating the sum of divisors code won't work properly Python

Tags: python

I have a code that should calculate the sum of divisors of a given number but it just won't work the way it should, what am I missing????

here is the code:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
  sumlist = []
  for i in range(n ,0 , -1):
    if n % i == 0:
      sumlist.append(i)
      n -= 1
    elif n % i != 0:
      pass
  fsum = sum(sumlist)
  return fsum

print(sum_divisors(0)) # sum of 0 = 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1 = 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18 = 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 = 144
```

and this is what I get as results:
`0 6 666 5253`

I'm still a beginner in this so any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from `n`?

Comment: It's not clear from your examples if 1 should be included or not.

Comment: One thing that you definitely can see in your code , is that the value is being added to the total , irrespective if it being a factor of all . For example , 5253 is what you will get if you go on adding 1+2+3+4+5+.....+101+102 . That's the error in the code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum_divs = []

    for i in range(1, n):
       if n % i == 0:
           sum_divs.append(i)

    return sum(sum_divs)

print(sum_divisors(0)) # sum of 0 = 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1 = 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18 = 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 1+2+3+6+17+34+51 = 114
```

Comment: Using `sum` with a generator (to skip the creation of a list) makes this a one-liner: `return sum(i for i in range(1, n) if n % i == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- `n -= 1` is wrong and ultimately leads to i and n always being equal, therefore `n % i == 0` always being true (therefore the large numbers you get) => delete this line
- `i` shouldn't start from `n`, since based on your expected results you don't want the number itself to be included in the sum of divisors. Therefore: `range(n - 1, 0, -1)` insteaf of `range(n ,0 , -1)`

Apart from this, your code has some unnecessary parts, like the `elif`. Consider GGberry's version for a cleaner style.

---

Or use a generator expression instead of the loops:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    return sum(i for i in range(1, n) if not n % i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lesson in debugging of *your* approach - there are better ones:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    sumlist = []
    for i in range(n ,0 , -1):
        if n % i == 0:
            sumlist.append(i)
#      n -= 1           # this does nothing valuable
#    elif n % i != 0:   # this does nothing
#      pass             # this does nothing
    fsum = sum(sumlist)

    # debugging what your func computes by printing it:
    print (n, sumlist, fsum, sep = " ==> ")  

    return fsum

sum_divisors(0) # sum of 0 = 0
sum_divisors(3) # Should sum of 1 = 1
sum_divisors(36) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18 = 55
sum_divisors(102) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 = 144 (wrong sum)
```

Outputs:

```
0 ==> [] ==> 0
3 ==> [3, 1] ==> 4
36 ==> [36, 18, 12, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] ==> 91
102 ==> [102, 51, 34, 17, 6, 3, 2, 1] ==> 216
```

According to what you want as result - you start to test your range with `n-1` instead of `n` to get there:

```
def fixed_sum_divisors(n):
    sumlist = []
    for i in range(n-1 ,0 , -1): # dont start with n
        if n % i == 0:
            sumlist.append(i)
    fsum = sum(sumlist)
    print (n, sumlist, fsum, sep = " ==> ")
    return fsum

fixed_sum_divisors(0) # sum of 0 = 0
fixed_sum_divisors(3) # Should sum of 1 = 1
fixed_sum_divisors(36) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18 = 55
fixed_sum_divisors(102) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 = 144 (wrong sum)
```

Output:

```
0 ==> [] ==> 0
3 ==> [1] ==> 1
36 ==> [18, 12, 9, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1] ==> 55
102 ==> [51, 34, 17, 6, 3, 2, 1] ==> 114  # your 144 is wrongly summed up
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a range like that isn't very efficient because once you get past the square root of n, any further tests are redundant.

I found a splendid implementation of a function that derives all factors of a given number [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800193/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-of-finding-all-the-factors-of-a-number-in-python)

I made a small modification to it and adapted it to this particular problem leading to:

```
from functools import reduce

def factors(n):
    return set(reduce(list.__add__,
                ([i, n//i] for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)+1, n % 2 + 1) if not n % i)))

def sum_divisors(n):
    return sum(factors(n)) - n
    
print(sum_divisors(102))
```

**Output:**

```
114
```

...and *not* 144 as suggested in the OP's question.

**Credit:**

@agf

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
for i in range(n ,0 , -1):
if n % i == 0:
  sumlist.append(i)
  n -= 1
```

n is being included.
Thus,

```
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1 = 1
```

will also include the 3 in the check, giving a result greater than what you want.

For some thing closer to what you want:

```
for i in range(n-1,0 , -1):
if n % i == 0:
  sumlist.append(i)
 # n -= 1  This should be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start your range ( in line 3 ) from n-1 , and then do it again whilst removing unnecessary code ( as mentioned in above answers ) .

Try this :

```
def sum_divisor(num): # Define your function here
    factors_list = [] # Create an empty list here
    for i in range(1,num): # Start your range from 1 and take it to n (beacuse the range will go on till n-1)
        if num % i == 0: # Check if it's divisible
            factors_list.append(i) # Append , if it's true

    total = sum(factors_list) # Add all the factors given in the list
    print(total) # Print 'em

input = int(input("Enter your data : "))
sum_divisor(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

As always when you work with divisors, you can speed up things a lot by just looping up to the square root of `n`. When you find a divisor `i` lower than the square root you know `n // i` is a divisor too.

This leaves us with some special cases to handle - especially so since you want to consider `1` as a divisor while not considering `n` itself. See this code:

```
def sum_divisors_sqrt(n):
    if n < 1:
        return 0
    sum_divs = [1]
    sqrt_n = int(sqrt(n))
    if n % sqrt_n == 0:
        sum_divs.append(sqrt_n)
    for i in range(2, sqrt_n):
        if n % i == 0:
            sum_divs.append(i)
            sum_divs.append(n//i)
    return sum(sum_divs)
```

On my PC this is 20x faster for `n = 1000`, 90x faster for `n = 10000`