# Why is x**3 slower than x*x*x?

Tags: python, numpy

In NumPy, x*x*x is an order of magnitude faster than x**3 or even np.power(x, 3).

```
x = np.random.rand(1e6)
%timeit x**3
100 loops, best of 3: 7.07 ms per loop

%timeit x*x*x
10000 loops, best of 3: 163 µs per loop

%timeit np.power(x, 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.15 ms per loop
```

Any ideas as to why this behavior happens?  As far as I can tell all three yield the same output (checked with np.allclose).

Comment: Integer vs. float calculations perhaps?

Comment: @RohitJain I don't think that's a particular useful link. The accepted answer to that question is "use numpy" and the question is about pure Python code, not NumPy.

Comment: @delnam forget the accepted answer look at the top voted answer.

Comment: @cmd The top rated answer is basically wrong. Taking the power is roughly O(1) since `x**y` is rewritten as `2**(y*log x)`. Both `2**a` and `log a` are single floating-point instructions on modern processors.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019932/15055), it's because the implementation of exponentiation has some overhead that multiplication does not. However, naive multiplication will get slower and slower as the exponent increases. An empirical demonstration:

```
 In [3]: x = np.random.rand(1e6)

 In [15]: %timeit x**2
 100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop

 In [16]: %timeit x*x
 100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop

 In [17]: %timeit x**3
 10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

 In [18]: %timeit x*x*x
 10 loops, best of 3: 27.2 ms per loop

 In [19]: %timeit x**4
 10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

 In [20]: %timeit x*x*x*x
 10 loops, best of 3: 42.4 ms per loop

 In [21]: %timeit x**10
 10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

 In [22]: %timeit x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x
 10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop

 In [24]: %timeit x**15
 10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

 In [25]: %timeit x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x
 1 loops, best of 3: 212 ms per loop
```

Note the exponentiation time stays more or less constant, except for the `x**2` case which I suspect is special-cased, while multiplication gets slower and slower. It seems you could exploit this to get faster integer exponentiation... for example:

```
In [26]: %timeit x**16
10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x
1 loops, best of 3: 225 ms per loop

In [28]: def tosixteenth(x):
   ....:     x2 = x*x
   ....:     x4 = x2*x2
   ....:     x8 = x4*x4
   ....:     x16 = x8*x8
   ....:     return x16
   ....:

In [29]: %timeit tosixteenth(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 49.5 ms per loop
```

It seems you could apply this technique generically by splitting any integer into a sum of the powers of two, computing each power of two as above, and summing:

```
In [93]: %paste
def smartintexp(x, exp):
    result = np.ones(len(x))
    curexp = np.array(x)
    while True:
        if exp%2 == 1:
            result *= curexp
        exp >>= 1
        if not exp: break
        curexp *= curexp
    return result
## -- End pasted text --

In [94]: x
Out[94]:
array([ 0.0163407 ,  0.57694587,  0.47336487, ...,  0.70255032,
        0.62043303,  0.0796748 ])

In [99]: x**21
Out[99]:
array([  3.01080670e-38,   9.63466181e-06,   1.51048544e-07, ...,
         6.02873388e-04,   4.43193256e-05,   8.46721060e-24])

In [100]: smartintexp(x, 21)
Out[100]:
array([  3.01080670e-38,   9.63466181e-06,   1.51048544e-07, ...,
         6.02873388e-04,   4.43193256e-05,   8.46721060e-24])

In [101]: %timeit x**21
10 loops, best of 3: 132 ms per loop

In [102]: %timeit smartintexp(x, 21)
10 loops, best of 3: 70.7 ms per loop
```

It's fast for small even powers of two:

```
In [106]: %timeit x**32
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop

In [107]: %timeit smartintexp(x, 32)
10 loops, best of 3: 57.4 ms per loop
```

But gets slower as the exponent gets larger:

```
In [97]: %timeit x**63
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

In [98]: %timeit smartintexp(x, 63)
10 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop
```

And not faster for large worst-cases:

```
In [115]: %timeit x**511
10 loops, best of 3: 135 ms per loop

In [114]: %timeit smartintexp(x, 511)
10 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
```

Comment: You have just discovered [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)...

Comment: @Jaime: indeed (I knew this existed already), and I wonder why numpy doesn't do it that way for integer exponents up to a certain size.. it seems a really easy speed gain

Comment: @Claudiu One possible reason is that virtually any kind of re-ordering or re-association of float arithmetic can change the results in subtle ways, and for quite a few use cases that is not acceptable. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6430448/395760

Comment: @delnan: ah perhaps. maybe there's standard expectations of `pow`, and if you want to do it another way (like exponentiation by squaring) you can implement it yourself (as I did here)

Comment: Python 2.7.5 evens out at power `5.`; 5 (int) is marginally slower than `5.` (float) due to type coercion.

Answer (score 7):

As a note if you are calculating powers and are worried about speed:

```
x = np.random.rand(5e7)

%timeit x*x*x
1 loops, best of 3: 522 ms per loop

%timeit np.einsum('i,i,i->i',x,x,x)
1 loops, best of 3: 288 ms per loop
```

Why einsum is faster is still an open question of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions). Although its like due to `einsum` able to use SSE2 while numpy's ufuncs will not until 1.8.

In place is even faster:

```
def calc_power(arr):
    for x in xrange(arr.shape[0]):
        arr[x]=arr[x]*arr[x]*arr[x]
numba_power = autojit(calc_power)

%timeit numba_power(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 51.5 ms per loop

%timeit np.einsum('i,i,i->i',x,x,x,out=x)
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop

%timeit np.power(x,3,out=x)
1 loops, best of 3: 609 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I expect it is because `x**y` must handle the generic case where both `x` and `y` are floats.  Mathematically we can write `x**y = exp(y*log(x))`.  Following your example I find

```
x = np.random.rand(1e6)
%timeit x**3
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

%timeit np.exp(3*np.log(x))
10 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop
```

I have not checked the actual numpy code but it must be doing something like this internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is because powers in python are performed as a float operation (this is true for numpy as well, because it uses C).

In C, the [pow function](http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/math.h/pow.php) provides 3 methods:

> double    pow (double x, double y)
>
> long  powl (long double x, long double y)
>
> float     powf (float x, float y)

Each of these are floating point operations.

Comment: this happens if x is floating, which would be a floating point operation in both cases.  Could explain your answer more.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spec](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#pow):

> The two-argument form pow(x, y) is equivalent to using the power
>   operator: x**y.
>
> The arguments must have numeric types. With mixed operand types, the
>   coercion  rules for binary arithmetic operators apply.

In other words: since `x` is a float, the exponent is converted from an int to a float, and the generic floating-point power operation is performed. Internally, this is usually rewritten as:

```
x**y = 2**(y*lg(x))
```

`2**a` and `lg a` (base 2 logarithm of `a`) are single instructions on modern processors, but it is still takes much longer than a couple of multiplications.

Answer (score -1):

```
timeit np.multiply(np.multiply(x,x),x)
```

times the same as `x*x*x`.  My guess is that `np.multiply` is using fast Fortran linear algebra package like BLAS.  I know from another issue that `numpy.dot` uses BLAS for certain cases.

---

I have to take that back.  `np.dot(x,x)` is 3x faster than `np.sum(x*x)`.  So the speed advantage to `np.multiply` is not consistent with using BLAS.

---

With my numpy (times will vary with machine and available libraries)

```
np.power(x,3.1)
np.exp(3.1*np.log(x))
```

take about the same time, but

```
np.power(x,3)
```

is 2x as fast.  Not as fast as `x*x*x`, but still faster than the general power.  So it is taking some advantage of the integer power.