# Faster matrix power than numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I needed to compute Q^N for quite a lot of various values of N *(between 1 to 10000)* and Numpy was a bit too slow.

I've asked on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499544/expressing-the-values-of-a-matrix-at-pow-n) if I could avoid to compute Q^N for my specific need and someone answered me that computing Q^N should be quite fast using the `P D^N P^-1` method.

So basically, instead of doing:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA
...
LA.matrix_power(m, N)
```

I've tried :

```
diag, P = LA.eig(m)
DN = np.diag(diag**N)
P1 = LA.inv(P)

P*DN*P1
```

And I obtain the same matrix as result *(tried on a single example)*

On a more complex matrix, Q:

```
% timeit.Timer('Q**10000', setup=setup).repeat(2, 100)
[5.87254786491394, 5.863131046295166]

% timeit.Timer('diag, P = linalg.eig(Q); DN=np.diag(diag**10000);P1=linalg.inv(P); P*DN*P1', setup=setup).repeat(2, 100)
[2.0032401084899902, 2.018735885620117]
```

And regarding my initial problem, the second method allows me to compute `P, diag and P1`only once and use it thousands of times. It's 8 times faster using this method.

**My questions are:**

- In which case it is not possible to use this last method to compute Q^N?
- Is it fine to use it in my case (matrix Q as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499544/expressing-the-values-of-a-matrix-at-pow-n))?
- Is there in numpy a function that already does it?

**Edit:**

- It appears that for another matrix, P is not invertible. So I am adding a new question: how can I change the matrix P so it becomes invertible but the resulting matrix is not too altered? I mean, it's ok if the values are close to the real result, by close I mean ~0.0001.

Comment: Regarding my 2 first questions, I guess Q must not be defective. But I don't know if my matrices are defective or not (because of my math background too far).

Comment: You could further speed this up by doing `diag**10000` using the exponentiation by squaring method. See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18453999/15055) where I implement it in numpy.

Comment: @Claudiu wow. I naively thought that diag**10000 would use the squaring method! However, in my case, I might even use the possibility to pass floating numbers anyway. That also something I could not use with LA.matrix_power.

Comment: You can do this as long as the matrix is diagonalizable. If the matrix Q is real and symmetric, you will always be able to perform this. Bonne chance, Maxime.

Comment: I agree wok, as I said before, I don't know if my matrices are defective or not (wikipedia says: "A square matrix which is not diagonalizable is called defective."). The matrix Q is not symmetric (it is triangular). Maybe I should do something with the determinant of the matrix, don't know, I need to dig on mathematic theorems I guess. Merci ;).

Comment: I know it is not what you asked, but if you want to do this stuf often, consider using Matlab. It is rather optimized towards matrix multiplication.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I intend to compute this into a simulation tool written in Python, it is not possible to do it with an external tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am partially answering my question:

According to the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L98), I think Numpy is using Exponentiation by Squaring:

```
# binary decomposition to reduce the number of Matrix
# multiplications for n > 3.
beta = binary_repr(n)
Z, q, t = M, 0, len(beta)
while beta[t-q-1] == '0':
    Z = N.dot(Z, Z)
    q += 1
result = Z
for k in range(q+1, t):
    Z = N.dot(Z, Z)
    if beta[t-k-1] == '1':
        result = N.dot(result, Z)
return result
```

Which is slower in my case, when `n` is large, than computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and compute M^N as equal to P D^N P^-1.

Now, regarding my questions:

> In which case it is not possible to use this last method to compute Q^N?

When some eigenvalues are equal, it will not be possible to invert P. someone has suggested to do it in Numpy on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1199). The answer was: "Your approach is only valid for non-defective dense matrices."

> Is it fine to use it in my case (matrix Q as given here)?

Not always, I might have several equal eigenvalues.

> Is there in numpy a function that already does it?

I think it is in SciPy: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.12.0/scipy/linalg/matfuncs.py#L57

So we can also do this:

```
LA.expm(n*LA.logm(m))
```

to compute m^n.

> How can I change the matrix P so it becomes invertible but the resulting matrix is not too altered? I mean, it's ok if the values are close to the real result, by close I mean ~0.0001.

I cannot simply add an epsilon value because the decomposition method is sensible when the values are too close. I'm pretty sure that could lead to unpredictable errors.

Comment: The matrix exponent option is interesting (i.e. using `la.expm`), but it seems to be even slower than `matrix_power` on my machine. Diagonalizing whenever possible is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

You have already figured out that your eigenvalues will be `(0, a, b, c, ..., 1)`. Let me rename your parameters, so that the eigenvalues are `(0, e1, e2, e3, ..., 1)`. To find out the eigenvector `(v0, v1, v2, ..., v(n-1))` corresponding to eigenvalue `ej`, you have to solve the system of equations:

```
v1                    = v0*ej
v1*e1 + v2*(1-e1)     = v1*ej
v2*e2 + v3*(1-e2)     = v2*ej
...
vj*ej + v(j+1)*(1-ej) = vj*ej
...
v(n-1)                = v(n-1)*ej
```

It is more or less clear that if all your `ei` are distinct, and none is equal to `0` or `1`, then the solution is well defined always, and when dealing with `ej`, the resulting eigenvector has the first `j` components non-zero, and the rest equal to zero. This guarantees that no eigenvector is a linear combination of the others, and hence that the eigenvector matrix is invertible.

The problem comes when some of your `ei` is either `0`, or `1`, or is repeated. I haven't been able to come up with a proof of it, but experimenting with the following code it seems that you should only worry if any two of your `ei` are equal and different from `1`:

```
>>> def make_mat(values):
...     n = len(values) + 2
...     main_diag = np.concatenate(([0], values, [1]))
...     up_diag = 1 - np.concatenate(([0], values))
...     return np.diag(main_diag) + np.diag(up_diag, k=1)
>>> make_mat([4,5,6])
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  4, -3,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  5, -4,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  6, -5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1]])
>>> a, b = np.linalg.eig(make_mat([4,5,6]))
>>> a
array([ 0.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  1.])
>>> b
array([[ 1.        ,  0.24253563, -0.18641093,  0.13608276,  0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.9701425 , -0.93205465,  0.81649658,  0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.31068488, -0.54433105,  0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.13608276,  0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.4472136 ]])
```

And now for some test cases:

```
>>> a, b = np.linalg.eig(make_mat([1,0,3])) # having a 0 or 1 is OK
>>> b
array([[ 1.        ,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.31622777,  0.57735027],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.9486833 ,  0.57735027],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.57735027]])
>>> a, b = np.linalg.eig(make_mat([1,1,3])) # repeating 1 is OK
>>> b
array([[ 1.        ,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.70710678]])
>>> a, b = np.linalg.eig(make_mat([0,0,3])) # repeating 0 is not OK
>>> np.round(b, 3)
array([[ 1.   , -1.   ,  1.   ,  0.035,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.105,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.314,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.943,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.447]])
>>> a, b = np.linalg.eig(make_mat([2,3,3])) # repeating other values are not OK
>>> np.round(b, 3)
array([[ 1.   ,  0.447, -0.229, -0.229,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.894, -0.688, -0.688,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.688,  0.688,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.447],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.447]])
```

Comment: I am currently reading your answer, thank you. But just a live comment: the sum of each line of my matrix is 1 (because it is a transition matrix of a markov chain).

Comment: Yes, that is taken into account. It is the `a`, `b`, `c`... that shouldn't be equal to each other, unless they are equal to `1`.

Comment: Ah ah indeed :). But a, b, c etc are in fact probabilities. That what I should have said sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In question:

> In which case it is not possible to use this last method to compute Q^N?

The key idea is to tell whether Q is diagonalizable. Equivalently, we should tell whether Q has n (number of its rows/columns) linearly independent eigenvectors. Note that distinct eigenvalues are just **sufficient** but **not necessary** condition of diagonalizability.