# Which is faster: x*x or x**2?

Tags: python, performance, mathematical-optimization, cpu-speed

I am trying to optimize my Python code.  Between:

```
y = x*x
```

or

```
y = x**2
```

if I need one trillion iterations in a speed-critical program, which one should I choose?

Comment: @ChrisHayes: I actually done it for [Gauss-Legendre Algorithm in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/347749/4279). At the time `x*x` was faster than `x**2`.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Python is used in a lot of scientific computing, despite being agonizingly slow (usually it is used to call optimized libraries like numpy).

Comment: You ever see the code the mathmeticians and engineers write? Microoptimisation is the least of their problems. :(

Comment: @roippi et al.
even after more than 4 years, I'm yet to understand why this question is "off-topic". Someone plz enlighten me or remove the "off-topic" honor.

Comment: This seems like a legitimate question.   On Python 3.6, `x*x` is about 3.5x faster than `x**2`.  Although lines of opcodes are equal via `dis` module, the implementations differ.  In CPython `ceval.c`, `x*x` uses [`PyNumber_Multiply`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31fb351211cb9c81d5878ad3518b3a7bf0211473/Objects/abstract.c#L959) and `binary_op1` while `x**2` uses [`PyNumber_Power`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/31fb351211cb9c81d5878ad3518b3a7bf0211473/Objects/abstract.c#L1002) and `ternary_op`.  It's not clear to me where the slow down occurs, but the latter is more complex.

Answer (score 3):

`x**2` is faster than `x*x`.

Implementation of exponent has some overhead in Python, so it is usually faster to use your custom multiplication `O(n)` with small multiplication count. `x*x*x*x*x` is way faster than `x**5`. Exponent time is a sort of constant. Your multiplication time is increasing with exponent parameter, so with a large parameter it is better to use exponent. However, with really very small parameter (2, in your case), exponent is faster than multiplication. And `x**2` is faster than `x*x`, although `x**3` is way slower than `x*x*x`. You can find a nice benchmark [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453999/2117492).

Comment: [`x*x` can be faster than `x**2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776706/python-which-one-is-faster-between-x2-or-xx#comment31142323_20776706). It seems you meant the reverse of what you said.

Comment: x**2 is a special case, and the speed difference in my tests was pretty small. So I guess it can also depend on x.