# Python rules of thumb that explain why * operator runs faster than **

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization, operators

My question is both specific (see example) and general. I am looking for best practices for writing fast-running python code. Of two or more ways of evaluating an expression or constructing a statement, I want to have an educated guess as to which will run faster *before* I do `timeit` comparison tests.

For example:

```
xx = [1,2,3,4,5]
x_bar = int(sum(xx)/len(xx)) # or = np.mean(xx)
x_c = [int(x_i - x_bar) for x_i in xx]
TSS = sum([x_i*x_i for x_i in x_c])
```

I thought I might speed things up by changing `x_i*x_i` to `x_i**2`. But if I am reading the results correctly, it was actually ~3 times slower:

```
%%timeit
sum([x_i*x_i for x_i in x_c])
# 670 ns ± 19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
sum([x_i**2 for x_i in x_c])
# 1.8 µs ± 120 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

An explanation of why this is true for the **`*`** operator vs. the **`**`** operator will be helpful. Even more helpful will be advice on principles, rules of thumb, and resources that will help me recognize opportunities to improve my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like the peephole optimizer doesn't recognize that `x_i**2` is `x_i*x_i`, and so is using the general algorithm `exp(2*log(x_i))` instead. In general, `x ** y` is *not* simply repeated multiplication.

Comment: I think you are saying that the compiler is not optimizing as you would expect it to. But I'm unclear which expression you would expect to run faster, `x_i**2` or `x_i*x_i`. Or would you expect the compiler to optimize them both to the same algorithm?

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453999/8069403 is quite interesting, the following discussion about compiler too

Comment: Thanks. For low powers multiplication is faster, but as the power goes up, exponentiation becomes faster than a string of multiplications. I think I need to look at the bytecode for each of these to see what is different.