# python - multiplication confusing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiplication

I was using the `timeit` module to find the time expense of different calculations and wanted to find the squares of numbers. What is confusing is that the power operator (`**`) takes too much time as compared to multiplying the number by itself. I thought that since it was made specifically for that purpose, it might be faster. Also, the `pow` function slows down. Can anyone explain the reason behind this confusing results? Can anyone help?

```
>>> timeit.timeit('x*x; x = 999;', 'x=999', number=10**8)
6.830663157197719
>>> timeit.timeit('x**2; x = 999;', 'x=999', number=10**8)
27.047929744404712
>>> timeit.timeit('mul(x, x); x = 999;', 'from operator import mul; x=999', number=10**8)
12.522030856840132
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(x, 2); x = 999;', 'x=999', number=10**8)
36.16042014302741
```

Why is this so?

Comment: I'd recommend reading this (current question is a possible duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019740/speed-of-calculating-powers-in-python